# JQuery alter flow by using alter dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function, if I use the alert dialog the Click section (1) is reached. if I remove the alert dialog the page is posted and the Click section (1) is never reacted. How can I i solve it?

```
$("#txtInput").change(function () {
  alert('...');
  $("#btn.ClientID").click(); // Click (1)
});
```

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the change event to call JavaScript function before posting back to the server. Then pass an event object into the function and then use preventDefault(). This stops the default behaviour.

```
$("#txtInput").change(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
  $("#btn.ClientID").click(); // Click (1) - It's unlikely "btn.ClientID" is the correct name of your button
});
```